# Qt tableView - add color

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtgui

How do I add color on the sides of a `tableView`?

[image]

Comment: Use `QStyledItemDelegate`

Comment: @Dmitry Sazonov how do I catch the property of the tableView? Qt :: DisplayRole? please explain with code, is better for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subclass QHeaderView and implement your own class like:

```
#include<QtWidgets>
class HeaderView: public QHeaderView
{
public:
  HeaderView():QHeaderView(Qt::Vertical)
  {}

   void paintSection(QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, int logicalIndex) const
   {
     QBrush brush;

     if(logicalIndex == 0)
        brush.setColor(QColor(Qt::red));
     else
        brush.setColor(QColor(Qt::blue));

     painter->fillRect(rect, brush); 
     QPen pen(Qt::white);
     painter->setPen(pen);     
     painter->drawText(rect,QString("Row %1").arg(logicalIndex));     
   }
};
```

Next set an instance of HeaderView as the vertical header of the QTableView:

```
HeaderView vView;    
tableview.setVerticalHeader(&vView);
```

Comment: Thanks, now it worked. Have to replace `tableview.setHorizontalHeader (&hView);` for `tableview.setVerticalHeader(&hView);`